# different types of parameters in javascript function

Tags: javascript, parameters

I am quite new to javascript. When going through the javascript codes, I have found ::

```
function Method1(sender, args) { ... }
function Method2(source, arguments) { ... }
```

When to use (sender, args) and (source, arguments)? What do they mean?

Comment: These are normal parameters, except `arguments` is reserved keyword and is _array-like_ object that contains all parameters passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments` is actually not a [JS reserved word](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1), otherwise your `Method2` would not have worked and would have thrown a Syntax Error.

When `arguments` is used in the parameters list of a function, it is simply a regular function parameter / argument, exactly like your `sender`, `source` and `args`.

It is true now that `Arguments` cannot be used as a class name. It is used internally by JavaScript to create an [`arguments` object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.6) (that is the one referred to by Tushar in the comments).

> When control enters an execution context for function code, an arguments object is created unless (as specified in 10.5) the identifier **arguments** occurs as an *Identifier* in the function’s *FormalParameterList* or occurs as the *Identifier* of a *VariableDeclaration* or *FunctionDeclaration* contained in the function code.

In every function, you can access all the parameters passed during that function call using this `arguments` array-like object. It is very useful for functions that may accept a non-predetermined (and possibly unlimited) number of parameters.

So what happens with your `Method2` is that it uses the same identifier "arguments" which now is assigned just a single parameter. As if it had *shadowed* the built-in `arguments` object.

Whereas if it had not been used in the parameters list, `arguments` within the function block would have been automatically assigned the list of all parameters.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5cexbrff/ (see result in the console)